# Used span to style certain words in list. It shifted other element to next row. Why and how to fix?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm working on a basic bootstrap project.

I used a span tag to style certain words in my list. Like this:

```
<li>The agile feline <span class="text-info" style="font-size:30px"><strong> squeezed through</strong></span> the fence</li><br>
```

and in doing so, it shifted my other bullet list(on right hand side) and empty middle column down to the next row. It's supposed to go:

```
List ------ Empty middle column -------  List
```

But instead looks like this:
List

```
Empty middle column ------ List    (<---with these ones on the next line; they should all be on same line)
```

Altogether, that section looks like this:

```
<div class="row bullet" style="margin-top:15px">
<div class="col-md-4 text-left">
  <ul class="bg-success">

    <li>Water is a<span class="text-info" style="font-size:30px"><strong> sacred element </strong></span> and the fundamental building block of ALL life</li><br>

    <li><span class="text-info" style="font-size:30px"><strong>Water</span> in its purist form, <span class="text-info" style="font-size:30px"><strong>cleanses</span>; both externally and <span class="text-info" style="font-size:30px"><strong> spiritually</span></li><br>

   <li><span class="text-info" style="font-size:30px"><strong>Preservation</span> of streams, springs and rivers <span class="text-info" style="font-size:30px"><strong>is vital</span></li><br>

   <li>Approximately <span class="text-info" style="font-size:30px"><strong>400 billion gallons</span> of water are used every day in the United States</li><br>

   <li>By 2025, half of the world’s population will be living in water-stressed areas.</li><br>

  </ul>
</div><!--left list-->   

  <div class="col-md-4 text-center bg-danger"></div><!--empty mid column-->

<div class="col-md-4">
  <ul class="bg-warning">

    <li class="right">844 million people in the world- one in ten- do not have access to an improved source of drinking water</li><br>

    <li class="right">Every minute a newborn baby dies from infection caused by a lack of clean water and an unclean environment. </li><br>

   <li class="right">Collectively, South African women and children walk a daily distance equivalent to 16 trips to the moon and back to fetch water</li><br>
   <li class="right">Globally, at least 2 billion people use a drinking-water source contaminated with feces</li><br>

  </ul>
</div><!--right list-->
```

Everything was laid out as it was supposed to be until I styled certain words using the span tag. I've done searches upon searches and haven't been able to find clear information to assist me through this. And I can't find any documentation of this specific issue either. I also came across the usage of span inside of a div like: div class="span".....
Now I'm confused if it should be inside of another div or its own tag??...

Comment: maybe it is caused by other styles. add your code in a snippet and recreate the problem in wuestion. Because by the code you have given I don't see any problem.

Comment: Working fine in jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jktgjrmb/. Can you reproduce the issue?

Comment: Hey thanks all, I'll try that.